# Ansible - Generating a file with template multiple loops

Tags: python-3.x, ansible

I have these variables:

```
ddns_domains:
  - domain: domain1.com
    hosts:
      - "@"
      - "cat"
      - "dog"
  - domain: domain2.com
    hosts:
      - "ghost"
      - "ship"
      - "house"
      - "door"
  - domain: domain3.com
    hosts:
      - "@"
      - "desk"
```

and I want to loop trough them and generate a file like this:

```
@ domain1.com
cat domain1.com
dog domain1.com
ghost domain2.com
ship domain2.com
house domain2.com
door domain2.com
@ domain3.com
desk domain3.com
```

I managed to debug them out correctly:

```
---
- name:
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.0.domain }} {{ item.1 }}"
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ ddns_domains }}"
    - hosts
```

But I can't make the template. I keep getting variable not defined error.

Any help is much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [template](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#)

```yaml
shell> cat ddns.txt.j2
{% for i in ddns_domains %}
{% for host in i.hosts %}
{{ host }} {{ i.domain }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The task below

```yaml
    - template:
        src: ddns.txt.j2
        dest: ddns.txt
```

gives what you want

```sh
shell> cat ddns.txt
@ domain1.com
cat domain1.com
dog domain1.com
ghost domain2.com
ship domain2.com
house domain2.com
door domain2.com
@ domain3.com
desk domain3.com
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It makes scense now. :)